# How to add words to any Android keyboard predictive dictionary programmatically?

Tags: android, android-service, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

Which file holds the database of words in Android keyboards and how to edit it or how to add words to personal dictionary by creating an application like shadowing the movement of a user iteratively and adding words to personal dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
UserDictionary.Words.addWord(Context, "Your Word", frequency, "Shortcut", Locale)
```

See this [UserDictionary.Words](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html#addWord(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale))

Comment: That only works if the keyboard uses the android user dictionary.  Which almost none of them do, because they need additional information it doesn't support (frequency, path lengths, context bigrams, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a real way to do this-  keyboards tend to manage their own user dictionaries, because no 2 keyboards store the exact same data in the same way.